# List of customers that have never rented out a movie from the top 5 actors (Sakila DB)

Tags: mysql, sql

In Sakila DB, how to get a list of customers that have never rented out even a single movie from the top 5 actors (the list of top actors is calculated by rental volume).

This is what I used to find the top 5 actors

```
SELECT a.actor_id, a.first_name, a.last_name, 
COUNT(r.rental_id) AS rentalVolume
FROM actor a
JOIN film_actor fa ON a.actor_id = fa.actor_id
JOIN film f ON fa.film_id = f.film_id
JOIN inventory i ON f.film_id = i.film_id
JOIN rental r ON i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id
GROUP BY a.actor_id, a.first_name, a.last_name
ORDER BY rentalVolume DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

I want to `SELECT` the `customer_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, that have never rented out a movie from these actors.

The desired result would be something like this

```
Customer Number      First Name        Last Name
      2                 PETER           OLIVIER
      8                 JOHN              DOE
      64                GWEN            LORENZO
```

Comment: @Gordon `the list of top actors is calculated by rental volume`

Comment: Are you definitely running SQL Server?

Comment: What's your issue?  How does your `customer` table relate to the actors?  Think you're missing something here...

Comment: Isn't Sakila DB a sample of a MySQL database and not a sample of a SQL Server database ?. You should check if you have the right tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `not exists` operator to search for the costumers that haven't any movie with the top 5 actors (to identify which of their rentals are movies with those actors you can use the `in` operator) :

```
select c.costumer_id, c.first_name, c.last_name
from costumers c
where not exists (
 select *
 from rental r
      inner join inventory i on i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id
      inner join film f on f.film_id = i.film_id
      inner join film_actor fa on fa.film_id = f.film_id and
                                  fa.actor_id in (<< Here_goes_your_top_5_actors_query >>)
 where r.costumer_id = c.costumer_id 
)
```

This is the most direct and easiest to understand translation of your logic to SQL, but a correlated subquery can result in very bad performance (specially when large numbers of records are involved). If this query is too slow for you, then you can do a select of rentals grouped by costumer, and summing their films that have one of those actors, returning only the costumers with a sum of zero.

The inner joins now have to be changed to left joins, because we are interested in rows that don't have not even a single film_actors matching the top 5 actors, so an inner join wouldn't return those costumers.

```
select c.costumer_id, c.first_name, c.last_name
from costumer c
     left join rental r on r.costumer_id = c.costumer_id
     left join inventory i on i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id
     left join film_actor fa on fa.film_id = i.film_id and
                                fa.actor_id in (<< Here_goes_your_top_5_actors_query >>)
group by c.costumer_id, c.first_name, c.last_name
having sum(fa.film_id) = 0
```

PS: in this faster query I have removed the join with films because it was never needed, we don't use any data from the film table, so we can directly join inventory to film_actor.